# Auto slide text over an image

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I have an image as shown below and text written at center of image.

[image]

**I have 10 text contents to be shown on image so i need to slide the text. I used marquee but it is not coming as slide show**. Please, anyone give me solution on how to slide my text on image.

**My code for marquee**

```
<div class="centered">
        <marquee direction="left">
            <p>Industrial IoT</p><span><a href="images/pdf/2018/Cell Tower Monitoring.pdf">Asset Management</a></span>
        </marquee>
      </div>

      <div class="centered">
        <marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="20">
            <p>Industrial IoT</p><span><a href="images/pdf/2018/Cell Tower Monitoring.pdf">Cell Tower Monitoring</a></span>
        </marquee>
      </div>

      <div class="centered">
        <marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="30">
            <p>Industrial IoT</p><span><a href="images/pdf/2018/Remote Monitoring Smart factory.pdf">Remote Monitoring Smart factory</a></span>
        </marquee>
      </div>

      <div class="centered">
        <marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="40">
            <p>Engineering Analytics</p><span><a href="images/pdf/Climate Control for Networking Laboratory.pdf">Climate Control for Networking Laboratory</a></span>
        </marquee>
      </div>

      <div class="centered">
        <marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="50">
            <p>SDN/NFV</p><span><a href="images/pdf/2018/Building SDN Compatibility in Legacy Devices for OEM.pdf">Building SDN Compatibility in Legacy Devices for OEM</a></span>
        </marquee>
      </div>

      <div class="centered">
        <marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="60">
            <p>SDN/NFV</p><span><a href="images/pdf/2018/Building Software Licensing Support for Virtual Network Functions (VNF).pdf">Building Software Licensing Support for Virtual Network Functions (VNF)</a></span>
        </marquee>
      </div>

      <div class="centered">
        <marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="70">
            <p>SDN/NFV</p><span><a href="images/pdf/2018/Building a Network Access Control (NAC) Capable SDN Controller.pdf">Building a Network Access Control (NAC) Capable SDN Controller</a></span>
        </marquee>
      </div>

      <div class="centered">
        <marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="80">
            <p>SDN/NFV</p><span><a href="images/pdf/Building a SD-WAN Solution for IoT Gateway.pdf">Building SD-WAN Solution for IoT Gateway</a></span>
        </marquee>
      </div>

      <div class="centered">
        <marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="90">
            <p>SDN/NFV</p><span><a href="images/pdf/2018/Building a SDN Controller with Zero Touch.pdf">Building a SDN Controller with Zero Touch Provisioning Capabilities</a></span>
        </marquee>
      </div>

      <div class="centered">
        <marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="10">
            <p>SDN/NFV</p><span><a href="images/pdf/2018/Enabling Network Function Virtualisation (NFV) Capabilities for OEM (1).pdf">Enabling Network Function Virtualisation (NFV) Capabilities for OEM</a></span>
        </marquee>
      </div>
```

Thank You in Advance!!!!

Comment: what is the output you get from your try & post css & html

Comment: Something like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/vvs5ex1b/

Comment: use any js slider - eg http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: @Ronvander that is what exactly I want thank you for the help

Comment: @pravinmurali thanks for helping me it also helps me for future things in my website.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```css
#display 
{ 
     position:absolute; 
     visibility:show; 
}
#text
{
    color:White;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:65%;
    top:2%;
}
marquee {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div id="display">
    <img height="100" width="100" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/28/21/14/lens-3114729_960_720.jpg" />
    <marquee id="m1" scrollamount="2" direction="up" loop="true" width="100%" heigth="100%">
    <center>
    <p id="text">
    Opening Soon !!!
    </p>
    </center>
    </marquee>
    </div>
```

Comment: ya but i have set of text in same div so one by ne the text should be sliding

Comment: like opening soon text there are 10 more text which follow that  so i need to keep sliding those text .

Comment: it's a support platform I have given a sample code. Extend it with your requirement.

Comment: add all text in between p tag

Comment: when i add text using marquee it is overlapping with the other one. That is problem i am facing